# Espresso perform click on view in Recyclerview item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I tried everything to perform click on view in recyclerview item but not succesfull. Read every option on internet and tried it but still not working. Lately I used:

```
onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.live_rw_liveMatchList))
    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(2, MyViewAction.clickChildViewWithId(R.id.pick_pw_pickLeft)));
```

But all i get is:

> android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'with id:
>   hr.psk.android:id/ticket_list_list' matches multiple views in the
>   hierarchy. Problem views are marked with '****MATCHES****' below.

And it matches only one view (my recyclerview with 13 childs)

I know this should work but it is not working in my project. Tried to perform only click on recyclerviw item in other recyclerview to make it more simple like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.ticket_list_list))
    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```

But it gives me the same message back -> Multiple matches problem

somebody help, I really tried everything

Comment: are you using stable ids or not?

Comment: Yes I use stable ids

Comment: Try my answer code it will work fine.

Comment: Please provide the log below the error message that you're seeing. You definitely have more than one view with the id `R.id.ticket_list_list`.

Comment: @Haris Have you got the answer or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onView(withId(R.id.ticket_list_list))
    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```

The error you're getting means that there's another View somewhere that also uses the id ***ticket_list_list***

**Is ticket_list_list your actual list view?** (the parent of the things that you want to click)

If it is then **is it the only one available on the screen?** if it is then use the following

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.ticket_list_list), isDisplayed()))
    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```

Adding the isDisplayed() Matcher makes the targeted View more specific by targeting only those that are displayed and ignoring those that are existing but not displayed

**If there really is another matcher displayed (or the above doesn't work for you)** that has the same id as the one you're trying to match then use the following

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.ticket_list_list), withParentIndex(index_of_matcher_here)))
    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```

Instead of isDisplayed() withParentIndex(some_number) should more specifically target and give you the view that has the id you're looking for along with the index of it

In the very messy instance that the above still doesn't work, maybe because all the returned Views have the same index possibly because they are the children of another View then you can get creative and do something like

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.ticket_list_list), withParent(allOf(withId(if_of_the_parent), withParentIndex(index_of_matcher_here)))))
    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```

to specify the index of the parent instead.

Just mix 'n match your way through it, just make sure to not go crazy on the Matchers and just keep things readable

*Use as little as you can (make sure it's readable and maintainable too and not just made up of indexes), you're not trying to get the coordinates for a missile target- you just want the View*

Answer (score 1):

I also face the same problem before few days but finally got the solutions from StackOverflow.

If you want to click recycler custom item view click then implement the following code in your project

You need to write this code in java this will help you a lot and saved your time

ClickOnButtonView is control a view action happened in the list item and 
UiController class helps you find custom row item

The code is written in **Kotlin**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class CampaignFragmentTest {

    @get: Rule
    val activityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(TestActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun testCustomListClick() {
        clickOnButtonAtRow(0)
    }
}

private fun clickOnButtonAtRow(position: Int) {
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.list)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
    (position, ClickOnButtonView()))
}

inner class ClickOnButtonView : ViewAction {
    internal var click = ViewActions.click()

    override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
        return click.constraints
    }

    override fun getDescription(): String {
        return " click on custom button view"
    }

    override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {
        //btnClickMe -> Custom row item view button
        click.perform(uiController, view.findViewById(R.id.btnClickMe))
    }
}
```

Comment: downvoting because you haven't explained why this would work,just pasting code as an answer is against stackoverflow rules

Comment: What the problem do you face when implemented above solution?

Comment: Returns me same error when crush like before:android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'with id: hr.psk.android:id/ticket_list_list' matches multiple views in the hierarchy. Problem views are marked with '****MATCHES****' below.

Comment: Can you post your layout code?, So we can get a better idea to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

That error means that it found multiple views with the id `R.id.ticket_list_list`. There should also be a view hierarchy log that follows the error message you provided, showing the views that Espresso found with that same id marked with `****MATCHES****`.

So you can either change the id of the view you want to test or target the view by providing another [ViewMatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers) as below:

```
onView(allOf(withId(recyclerViewID), viewMatcher))
    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can also create your own custom click action like this :

```
    fun customActionClickOnItemEvent(
        @NonNull targetViewId: Int
    ): ViewAction {
    
        return object : ViewAction {
    
            val click = ViewActions.click()
    
            override fun getDescription(): String = "Item clicked"
    
            override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> = click.constraints
    
            override fun perform(uiController: UiController?, view: View?) {
                click.perform(uiController,view?.findViewById(targetViewId))
            }
        }
    }
```

And Calling this function like this :

```
 onView(withId(R.id.rv_products)).perform(
            RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(
                1,
                customActionClickOnItemEvent(R.id.img_wish_list)
            )
        )
```